# PHP multidimensional array, how do I grab values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array in PHP that contains several arrays, like below.

I want to be able to grab the values that comes from one brand at the time. For example: grab all sizes, all materials and all colors that has the brand number 55. Have looked on tutorials on how to get values from multidimensional arrays but I just can't get it to work.

```
Array (

[0] => Array ( [size_1] => 7 [brand] => 45 )

[1] => Array ( [size_1] => 13 [brand] => 55 )

[2] => Array ( [material_1] => 7 [brand] => 45 )

[3] => Array ( [material_1] => 17 [brand] => 55 )

[4] => Array ( [material_2] => 15 [brand] => 45 )

[5] => Array ( [material_3] => 16 [brand] => 45 )

[6] => Array ( [material_4] => 8 [brand] => 45 )

[7] => Array ( [material_5] => 9 [brand] => 45 )

[8] => Array ( [material_5] => 11 [brand] => 86 )

[9] => Array ( [color_1] => 1093 [brand] => 55 )

[10] => Array ( [color_1] => 3064 [brand] => 54 )

[11] => Array ( [color_2] => 1687 [brand] => 55 )

[12] => Array ( [color_3] => 2297 [brand] => 55 )

[13] => Array ( [color_4] => 1280 [brand] => 55 )

[14] => Array ( [color_5] => 2822 [brand] => 55 )

)
```

Comment: Have you used a `foreach` before

Comment: Maybe you should look at how you create this array and create it in the format you want with only that data you want. Does this come from a query against the database

Comment: A combination of array_column() and array_filter() perhaps?

Comment: Iterate thru the array values while checking for the particular value you want then when you get it,  identify its index at that point and use this index to get the size, material and color at that index.